# How may I delete files in the trash without having sufficient access rights?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, trash

How can I delete files inside the trash folder I have not sufficient access rights for? It shouldn't be important for my question, but I'm using Gnome and can't delete in nautilus and don't know where the trash is located in the cmd. I'm using my ordinary Ubuntu-account.

[image]

Comment: not much to go on here... is it your profiles Trashbin ? another users ? Window manger? e.g. Gnome?, KDE?, XFCE?, etc... File manager abilities would be dictated by the above information.
or, if there is another standalone File manager is installed. but basically...
login as root.
browse to the users Trashbin.
delete permanently(should be a right-click option) personally. i don't use the trashbins, or, recyclers.
i figure i'm getting rid of it... so.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about how you managed to get those folders in your user's trash folder without moving them there on purpose, however: your user's trash folder is located in `~/.local/share`;

You may manually empty the trash just by removing the whole folder (it will be recreated when a new file / folder is moved to the trash):

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Comment: This worked. FYI: I just moved them into the trash in nautilus.

Comment: @empedokles What I don't understand is that you shouldn't have been able to move folders owned by root regardless. The only way would be to do it from a `nautilus` root instance, but in that case the folders would have been moved to root's trash in `/root/.local/share/Trash`. Indeed I'm missing something here. However glad that it worked